# Is there anyway to change default values for php curl options, for a script session or globally?

Tags: php, curl, global

I'm using a framework which has curl handling encapsulated in the depths of it's class hierarchy. Basically I would like to change the way it does handle curl, without patching the files. It could be ideal if I could change curl defaults globally form outside. In php.ini or in similar way.

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most part, this can only be done with a reference to the cURL handle being used.

There is only one php.ini directive for cURL (`curl.cainfo`) as of PHP 5.3.7:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php

Comment: this is no longer true, there is a `curl.cainfo` setting which can be set via php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Basically you set curl options on opened curl handler with curl_setopt. If you library doesn't allow you to manipulate the handler you cannot change any options.

Looks like in your case the only way is to either overload library classes or patch them.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11682254/3486547

Per the above answer

> With this PHP command:
>
> ```
> ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000);
> ```
>
> Or add/update the .htaccess file with this line:
>
> ```
> php_value default_socket_timeout 6000
> ```
>
> Check the current value with phpinfo()