# Cannot install ruby using RVM in Cygwin - curl SSL cert problem

Tags: ruby, curl, cygwin, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby using RVM in Cygwin, but I'm getting the error:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

i've looked at this question: [Curl Certificate Error when Using RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2)

but unfortunately the solution doesn't work for me because `curl-config --ca` doesn't show anything. I checked with `curl-config --configure` and it seems the package was compiled with the `--without-ca-bundle`

how can I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2) is the same question.  open ~/.rvm/scripts/fetch and edit every "fetch_command=..." line to have a -k option.

Comment: thanks. somehow I missed that answer. alternatively I realized that I could just put -k in curlrc

Comment: I was debugging this problem.  The CURL_CA_BUNDLE fix didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems curl in cygwin isn't shipped with its CA certificates bundle. You can download it at http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem then use:

```
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=</path/to/cacert.pem> rvm install <ruby>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ~/.rvm directory then do `which rvm` and then edit [rvm-path]/../scripts/fetch.  Each curl command need -k. Ie:

```
...

  fetch_command="curl -k -x${rvm_proxy} -f -L --create-dirs -C - " # -s for silent

else

  fetch_command="curl -k -f -L --create-dirs -C - " # -s for silent
...
```

This worked for Cygwin.