# Rvm having issue installing ruby, please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I just installed rvm and am trying to install ruby, and it's giving me an error message. Can anyone help?

```
alex$ type rvm | head -1 

rvm is a function

alex$ rvm install 1.9.2

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your connection...

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The default
 bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/alex/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The default
 bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
**ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/alex/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.**
```

Comment: What OS are you using? And do you use a proxy?

Comment: Why is it trying to use SSL for the `http://` URL. That isn't right.

Comment: I'm not sure, rvm seems to be installed though. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the system time correct - i.e. today's date & time?

Comment: yes, seems like it. why?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue before when installing on 10.5 - I think I ended up installing the head version; for whatever reason that did not have the same SSL issue

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-head
```

I would check the answer on this post first, might do the trick? [Curl Certificate Error when Using RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue, and found that updating curl solved it swiftly.