# RVM installation fails

Tags: ruby, rvm

I followed the instructions from the RVM homepage (https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

I typed the following:

```
sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

the script executed and didn't seem to give any errors.

the same without sudo gave an error:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/wayneeseguin-rvm-stable.tgz: Permission 
Warning: denied
  0  792k    0  3908    0     0   2257      0  0:05:59  0:00:01  0:05:58  2257
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 3908)

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/stable'.
  curl returned status '23'.
```

I also put this in my ~/.bashrc

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

what I get is:

```
~$ type rvm | head -1
bash: type: rvm: not found

~$ source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

~$ source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
bash: /home/anonym/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

How can this be fixed?

PS

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Did you try reloading your session after changing your .bashrc? To do that, use `source ~/.bashrc` or open new terminal window.

Comment: Are you trying to install RVM for your own personal development, or as a system administrator for all users on a shared host? Unless you are a system admin doing it for everyone, you should use the single user installation, per RVM's install page.

Comment: i got this because i'm behind a proxy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
$ curl -s raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
```

or

```
$ curl -s raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | sudo bash -s stable
```

depending on your permissions. That should help. It helped me! :)

Comment: In works if you either use it with sudo or if you create a directory with permissions to write first.

Comment: Make sure you've added your user to the rvm group.  Also, make sure you log out and log in.  Group memberships are processed at login, so in order to write to /usr/local/rvm, you must log out and then log in so that the OS recognizes that you're in the rvm group.

Answer (score 33):

Sudo problems. This worked for me to install rvm. Just do:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby
```

Comment: useful for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @hec Life saver answer :)

Answer (score 16):

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

at the bottom of the file add these line

```
unset rvm_path
unset GEM_HOME
```

Then run

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.3
rvm use 2.1.3 --default
ruby -v
```

Comment: I had to `source ~/.bashrc` before curl would work for me, but it did!

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to fix this, but I ran into the same issue and was kinda in a hurry, so I went for a quick and dirty workaround:

```
$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer > foo.sh
$ chmod 755 foo.sh
```

Then edit line 162, and add -k to the curl command:

```
$ vim foo.sh
162 if curl -Lk https://github.com/${_repo}/rvm/tarball/${_branch} -o ${rvm_archives_path}/${_repo}-rvm-${_branch}.tgz
```

Then run the script:

```
$ ./foo.sh --branch stable
```

Like I said, not ideal, but it got me where I needed to be quickly.

Comment: kept digging a little, found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2.  In particular, the answer from @dbikard with instructions for updating the cacert bundle for curl.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me on AWS Centos 5 images.

Comment: this solution "works" for me partially since I had to go inside my foo.sh file and replace

https://github.com/

by

https://nodeload.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has this problem in the future in ubuntu I was getting this error because of an old package that still had config stuff hanging around.

Try running

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
```

That should take care of the permission error and let you install RVM as a normal user under $HOME/.rvm

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your .bashrc instead (without `echo`)

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

And restart your terminal.

Comment: It didn't help. Anyway there is no such directory.

Comment: Then your first step have gone wrong. Do you have a log from it? Or can you retry?

Answer (score 1):

You might have RVM installed under the wrong user. RVM won't let you install if it's installed under another user.

You can uninstall it from the other user with `rvm implode`.

Log over to the other user and RVM will install correctly!

Answer (score 0):

https://rvm.io/rvm/security#ipv6-issues
You can forbid gpg's internal dirmngr from using IPv6 by add the following line to ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf: