# My install of RVM on a Ubuntu 8.04.4 machine fails. Should I install it as multi-user instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am currently attempting to install RVM on an Ubuntu server using version 8.04.4.

At the moment I am a attempting a single user install. I am the only person who administers this machine and I am still pretty noobish at this. I am currently following he installations guide on the RVM site and added the 'k' flag to the curl command. The complaints about the certificate still do not go away.

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none


Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/stable'.
  curl returned status '77'.
```

My ultimate goal is merely to upgrade ruby from v1.8.6 to 1.9.2 on this machine.

I've noticed many people recommending against a multi-user installation which is why I have yet to attempt it. Is it recommended that I try a multi-user installation? If not can someone assist me in eradicating this certificate issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bunch of solutions [here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2), do any of them help?

Comment: gonna try getting a CA cert from [The Haxx Page](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) referenced there. I'll keep you posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it single user. Your problem isn't RVM though -- it's the CA certs.

Read this link and make sure your SSL is up to date, and you have installed the CA certs:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL

To install ca certs on Ubuntu using apt:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: hmm. I don't have the CA certs only what seems to be self-signed? snake-oil certs    e.g. b14d9f7c -> ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

Comment: that did it. Thank you so much. Single user install successful. :). I'd upvote this if I could :/

Answer (score 0):

according to `man curl` this problem is:

```
77     Problem with reading the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?).
```

I guess you have sissues with access rights to the mentioned file:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

make sure is readable for all users:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/ /etc/ssl/ /etc/ssl/certs/
sudo chmod 644 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: i don't have that file at all just the ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem in my /etc/ssl/certs/ directory. Guess that means I have to obtain one?