# SSL certificate error when installing rvm

Tags: ruby, command-line, rvm

Hi I'm trying to install RVM onto a Mac OsX v 10.4.11.

Into the terminal I type:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I receive this message:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    387      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The default
 bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I found similar questions on StackOverflow eg [Curl Certificate Error when Using RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2), but a) this is a problem with installing RVM in the first place, not using RVM to install a new version of Ruby and more importantly b)the best answers to similar questions have suggested this is an error generated when referring to RVM's old site ie. rvm.beginrescueend.com. The solution given is to use

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

which is what I am using but which is generating, for me, this error message, and hence why I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Phillip

Comment: Add the `-k` switch `curl -k -L ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I installed RVM successfully on Mac OS X Server 10.4.11.

You need:

- **Xcode 2.5**, the latest Xcode for Tiger
- **[MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts)** installed, configured, and up-to-date
- **[gcc-4.2](http://r.research.att.com/tools/)** Apple build 5566, instructions later...

---

## curl

We need curl to use newer certs. Download an up-to-date [certificate bundle](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), and configure curl to use it. Note the `cacert.pem` path must be absolute.

```
mkdir ~/.certs
curl -o ~/.certs/cacert.pem http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
echo cacert = \"/Users/your-username/.certs/cacert.pem\" >> ~/.curlrc
```

---

## Upgrade bash

Next, to properly execute RVM's install script, we must upgrade bash. I used the latest release, version 4.2.

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
curl -C - -O ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz # letter O, not a zero
tar zxf bash-4.2.tar.gz
cd bash-4.2
./configure && make && sudo make install
sudo bash -c "echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /private/etc/shells"
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
cd /bin
sudo mv bash bash-old
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash bash
```

Log into a new shell, and you should be running bash 4.2.

```
bash --version
#=> GNU bash, version 4.2.0(1)-release (powerpc-apple-darwin8.11.1)
#=> ...
```

---

## Upgrade libtool

Use macports to upgrade the libtool package. This step is necessary to properly configure yaml.

Make sure macports is up-to-date and ready to go.

```
sudo port install libtool
```

This will take bloody ages, for there are many dependencies to compile. Grab a sandwich.

---

## Install gcc-4.2

Your rubies will not compile yet because it tries to use gcc-4.2, which Xcode 2.5 doesn't provide. We must install it ourselves. Download it from AT&T Research:

```
curl -C - -O http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-4.2-5566-darwin8-all.tar.gz
```

Apple packed this tarball relative to the root directory (`/`), so this one-liner will extract everything into place.

```
sudo tar fvxz gcc-4.2-5566-darwin8-all.tar.gz -C /
```

Done.

---

## Install RVM.

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

RVM should install, yaml and ruby should compile, and you should be good to go.

While installing rails and friends, documentation conversion to UTF-8 gave me warnings, which I'm not too concerned about. The important parts installed without a hiccup.

I am running Mac OS X Server 10.4.11 Build 8S2169 on a Mac Server G4 (QS2002) DP 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions I will give this a go

Answer (score 1):

Does `echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc` work for you? I don't actually use a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the message, it tells you what to do.

David suggestion will work, but remember it brings all your downloads via curl or git into insecure mode - not validating if the certificate is trusted.

As a hint you might get this answers also helpful (more then the error you got):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7599151/497756
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901540/497756
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817139/497756

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestions but I'm still running into problems. I've tried both

Comment: Using -k and echo insecure I still get the same error message, now starting with `warning: 'insecure' had unsupported trailing garbage`. I get the same warning when following the penultimate instruction of the first link you gave me. The second link I don't understand, sorry I'm new to command line I'm just trying to install RVM to update my Ruby to install SASS. When I type in the first line I get `wget: command not found`. With the instructions in the last link I get Permission denied on the last command even when using sudo.

Comment: I just tried `curl -k -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` again and now I get a different message, it still starts with the trailing garbage warning, but now instead of talking about SSL Certificates it says `bash: line 5: 65536 * 2 + 256 * 05b: value too great for base (error token is "05b")
bash: line 14: set: errtrace: invalid option name
bash: line 27: conditional binary operator expected`. What am I doing wrong here? Sorry if I am being an idiot.

Comment: @user1143666 it might be your system, we test RVM with OSX 10.6 ... but not with 10.4 ... it might work with 10.5 but no guaranties to that.

Comment: ok looks like I need a new computer, as I can't go any higher than 10.4.11 on this one, thanks for your help