# SSL certificate failed for twitteR in R

Tags: r, ssl, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I know similar questions have been asked again. However, I've tried everything I found here and on google and nothing seems to work for me.

My code is the following:

```
reqURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=reqURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL,
                         authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

Here I get:
`[1] TRUE`

But if I try this:
`tweets = searchTwitter('blabla', n=1500)`

I get the following error:
    `[1] "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
  Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Here are the packages and versions on my PC:

> sessionInfo()
>       R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
>       Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ROAuth_0.9.2   digest_0.6.2   twitteR_1.1.0  rjson_0.2.12  
[5] RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Any help would be really useful!!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9916283/1036500 (I couldn't make it work either...)

Comment: Just to add a bit of paranoia: Not EVERY SSL certificate failure is a programming error, some of them are actual attacks (i.e. your employer, government or other third party substituting an invalid certificate). Does Twitter work fine in Google Chrome for you?

Comment: Yes it does, why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 18):

Do the following first, and then run your code:

```
library(RCurl) 

# Set SSL certs globally
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
```

This usually corrects the issue you were experiencing.

**EDIT (Aug 2014):** *Or better yet, try to use the httr package instead (which is a friendly wrapper of RCurl with useful default options set for you)*

Answer (score 2):

finally i got the solution, please try this method. this is very easy

```
library(devtools)
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)

api_key = "aaa"
api_secret = "bbb"
access_token = "ccc"
access_token_secret = "ddd"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update your cacert.pem file. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/442797) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6414232/1478381) for links to other questions regarding this. I see this hasn't worked for other people using `download.file()`, but this might using Curl directly. You can update your bundle file like so:

```
system( paste0( "curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o " , tempdir() , "/cacert.pem" ) )
#Then you can use it like so
twitCred$handshake( cainfo = paste0( tempdir() , "/cacert.pem" ) )
```

HTH

Comment: Thank Simon but it doesn't seem to work for me. Why so many people have the same problem with twitter API? Something else I could try?