# Download tweets with R

Tags: r, ssl-certificate, tweets

I've been trying to download tweets with the twitteR package in a new PC:

```
library(twitteR)
z<-searchTwitter("#gold",n=1500)
```

and I get the following error message:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
Details:\nerror:14090086:SSL      
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" 
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) :   
Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Could you please help me on solving this issue?

Comment: Please see this answer as it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347233/ssl-certificate-failed-for-twitter-in-r

Comment: Have a look at the `Related` questions linked on the right of the page (as well as the link Joey suggests!). This problem has come up many times, and one of the answers under those questions may help you. If those answers don't help, please update the question, with **exactly** what you did (i.e. how you connected to the twitter api in the first place, minus your consumerkey and secret of course!), and things like `sessionInfo()` and `packageVersion('twitteR')`. We at least need to know what platform you are running on.