# Can I change default_socket_timeout from my php code?

Tags: timeout, php

In my php script I restore db2 database backups. They are getting bigger and bigger. So now I was getting 500 Server Error after +-30min after executing the script. There was this line in `(mod_fastcgi.c.3352) response not received, request sent: 634 on socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:9090 for /wrational/restoredb.php?mode=restore&database=RATIONAL, closing connection` in php-errors.log file.

I thought that setting `set_time_limit(6000);1 would solve the issue but it hasn't.

Increasing `default_socket_timeout` in php.ini file did the trick.

Is there any way to change `default_socket_timeout` from php code?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With this PHP command:

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000);
```

Or add/update the .htaccess file with this line:

```
php_value default_socket_timeout 6000
```

Check the current value with `phpinfo()`

Comment: I get an internal error: `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` when I add `php_value default_socket_timeout 6000` to my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 6):

beware of the fact, that php has a bug with default_socket_timeout and SSL. It will wait endless in case you use HTTPS/SSL.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41631

Comment: the bug was fixed in recent php versions
- 5.4.33
- 5.5.17
- 5.6.0-rc4

Comment: Is it fixed in 7.x versions?

Comment: If it is fixed in 5.4 then it's fixed in 7 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

you can add/update the .htaccess file 
line php_value default_socket_timeout 6000